# Linkage disequilibrium with multiple alleles and loci

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, theoretical-biology, population-dynamics, population-biology

Linkage disequilibrium $\left(D\right)$ for two bi-allelic loci is defined as:

$$D=X_{11}X_{22} - X_{12}X_{21}$$

where $X_{11},\ X_{12},\ X_{21},\ X_{22}$ are the frequencies of the haplotypes $A_1B_1$, $A_1B_2$, $A_2B_1$, $A_2B_2$ respectively (the subscript number correspond to the two different alleles and $A$ and $B$ correspond to the two different loci)

**My questions are**

- How is $D$ defined for more loci and a greater number of alleles?
- How is $D$ defined when the number of alleles differ from locus to locus?

Comment: Let me know if my answer is making sense to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LD describes the associations among alleles at different loci. For anything more than two bi-allelic loci, you need more than just one number to fully describe the associations. For instance, if we have three bi-allelic loci 1-3, we need the three pairwise LD coefficients, plus one extra three-way coefficient. In general, if we have $K$ loci, and the $k^\text{th}$ locus has $n_k$ alleles, there are $\prod_k n_k$ possible haplotypes, so to fully describe the state of the population we need $\prod_k n_k-1$ haplotype frequencies. If we instead want to use allele frequencies and associations, we'll therefore need $$\prod_k n_k-1-\sum_k(n_k-1)=\prod_k n_k-\sum_k n_k+k-1$$ LD coefficients. (Note that each locus is described by $n_k-1$ allele frequencies.) This means that things get complicated pretty quickly with many loci! If you want to dive into the details, check out [Barton and Turelli (1991)](http://www.genetics.org/content/127/1/229.short) and [Kirkpatrick, Johnson, and Barton (2002)](http://www.genetics.org/content/161/4/1727.short).

Answer (score 1):

Being a typical molecular biologist, I am a little uncomfortable with classical genetics terms. I might redefine some symbols (perhaps to mean the same) [*It is like talking to oneself while thinking*].

---

There are four DNA-blocks : A<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub> and B<sub>2</sub>. A<sub>k</sub> and B<sub>k</sub> are adjacent blocks. [*Perhaps this is same as what you defined the symbols as*]. A and B are contiguous DNA regions whereas 1 and 2 are different chromosomes (homologous regions). See the figure below.

[image]

The formula:

**D=X<sub>11</sub>X<sub>22</sub> - X<sub>12</sub>X<sub>21</sub>**

basically means that the difference between the probability that the loci are in `configuration I` (`11 & 22`) or `configuration II (swapped)` (`12 & 21`). Lets say there is a third region (3) which is homologous to the two *alleles* which has DNA-blocks A<sub>3</sub> and B<sub>3</sub>.

As LD is defined it is a difference in probabilities. Depending on how you define, it will take a negative or a positive value. When you have 3 recombinationally feasible *alleles* then there can be six cases:

1. C<sub>1</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>]
2. C<sub>2</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>3</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>2</sub>]
3. C<sub>3</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>3</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>1</sub>]
4. C<sub>4</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>2</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>1</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>3</sub>]
5. C<sub>5</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>2</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>3</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>1</sub>]
6. C<sub>6</sub>: [A<sub>1</sub>B<sub>3</sub>] [A<sub>2</sub>B<sub>1</sub>] [A<sub>3</sub>B<sub>2</sub>]

In this case there is no single measure for *difference*. You can also do something like this:

```
LD1' = P(C1) + P(C2) - (P(C3) + P(C4) + P(C5) + P(C6))
```

*Where LD<sub>1'</sub> is LD of region 1 and P(C<sub>m</sub>) is the frequency of m<sup>th</sup> configuration.*

Now, if there are 3 or more adjacent DNA blocks, you can only define LD, pairwise. It however, makes sense because linkage reduces with distance and you can calculate LD<sub>AC</sub> = LD<sub>AB</sub> x LD<sub>BC</sub> 
(*A,B and C are contiguous in alphabetical order. If A and B are not linked then A and C cannot be linked.*)